# Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status

Tags: r

I am using this site for reference:
http://r4ds.had.co.nz/introduction.html
but I am unable to install the tidyverse package. Using `dependencies = TRUE` did not help. What else can I do?

```
 installing *source* package ‘curl’ ...
** package ‘curl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libcurl' found
Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libcurl' found
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
Using PKG_LIBS=-lcurl
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libcurl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libcurl_dev (Solaris)
If libcurl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libcurl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘curl’
* removing ‘/home/akriti/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/curl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘openssl’ ...
** package ‘openssl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
Using PKG_LIBS=-lssl -lcrypto
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because openssl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: openssl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libssl_dev (Solaris)
 * brew: openssl@1.1 (Mac OSX)
If openssl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a openssl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘openssl’
* removing ‘/home/akriti/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/openssl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘openssl’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘evaluate’ ...
** package ‘evaluate’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (evaluate)
* installing *source* package ‘highr’ ...
** package ‘highr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (highr)
* installing *source* package ‘markdown’ ...
** package ‘markdown’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c Rbase64.c -o Rbase64.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c Rinit.c -o Rinit.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c Rmarkdown.c -o Rmarkdown.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c autolink.c -o autolink.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c buffer.c -o buffer.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c houdini_href_e.c -o houdini_href_e.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c houdini_html_e.c -o houdini_html_e.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c html.c -o html.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c html_smartypants.c -o html_smartypants.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c markdown.c -o markdown.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c stack.c -o stack.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o markdown.so Rbase64.o Rinit.o Rmarkdown.o autolink.o buffer.o houdini_href_e.o houdini_html_e.o html.o html_smartypants.o markdown.o stack.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /home/akriti/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/markdown/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (markdown)
* installing *source* package ‘yaml’ ...
** package ‘yaml’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c api.c -o api.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c dumper.c -o dumper.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c emitter.c -o emitter.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c implicit.c -o implicit.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c loader.c -o loader.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c parser.c -o parser.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c r-ext.c -o r-ext.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c reader.c -o reader.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c scanner.c -o scanner.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I. -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c writer.c -o writer.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o yaml.so api.o dumper.o emitter.o implicit.o loader.o parser.o r-ext.o reader.o scanner.o writer.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /home/akriti/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/yaml/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (yaml)
* installing *source* package ‘htmltools’ ...
** package ‘htmltools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/home/akriti/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/home/akriti/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c template.cpp -o template.o
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o htmltools.so RcppExports.o template.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /home/akriti/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/htmltools/libs
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (htmltools)
* installing *source* package ‘base64enc’ ...
** package ‘base64enc’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c base64.c -o base64.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c uriencode.c -o uriencode.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c utf8.c -o utf8.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o base64enc.so base64.o uriencode.o utf8.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /home/akriti/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/base64enc/libs
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (base64enc)
* installing *source* package ‘xml2’ ...
** package ‘xml2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Package libxml-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libxml-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libxml-2.0' found
Package libxml-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libxml-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libxml-2.0' found
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
Using PKG_LIBS=-lxml2
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because libxml-2.0 was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libxml2-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libxml2-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libxml2_dev (Solaris)
If libxml-2.0 is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libxml-2.0.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘xml2’
* removing ‘/home/akriti/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/xml2’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘xml2’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘caTools’ ...
** package ‘caTools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c Gif2R.cpp -o Gif2R.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c GifTools.cpp -o GifTools.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c runfunc.c -o runfunc.o
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o caTools.so Gif2R.o GifTools.o runfunc.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /home/akriti/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/caTools/libs
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (caTools)
* installing *source* package ‘rprojroot’ ...
** package ‘rprojroot’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (rprojroot)
ERROR: dependencies ‘curl’, ‘openssl’ are not available for package ‘httr’
* removing ‘/home/akriti/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/httr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘knitr’ ...
** package ‘knitr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** demo
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (knitr)
ERROR: dependencies ‘xml2’, ‘httr’ are not available for package ‘rvest’
* removing ‘/home/akriti/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/rvest’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rvest’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘rmarkdown’ ...
** package ‘rmarkdown’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (rmarkdown)
ERROR: dependencies ‘httr’, ‘rvest’, ‘xml2’ are not available for package ‘tidyverse’
* removing ‘/home/akriti/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/tidyverse’
Warning in install.packages :
 *installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: What version of R are you using? What OS?

Comment: Ubuntu or Windows?

Comment: I am using R version : 3.2.3 on Ubuntu

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You find the answer in your error message:

```
------------------------ ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
....
....
```

Copy and paste the following to your Terminal and than try installing `tidyverse` again. Should solve the problem.

```
# Required for many packages
sudo apt-get install -y libxml2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev
```

Comment: Excellent. This fixed it for me.

Comment: When I try this, it says "Error: unexpected symbol in "sudo apt" "

Comment: @KathiravanMeeran what is the unwanted symbol that you typed in the command

Answer (score 11):

The problem occurred because `tidyverse` has system dependencies (i.e., `libcurl4-openssl-dev`, `libssl-dev`, `libxml2-dev`). I wrote a [blog post](https://blog.zenggyu.com/en/post/2018-01-29/installing-r-r-packages-e-g-tidyverse-and-rstudio-on-ubuntu-linux/) that explains the solution in more details.

Comment: Based on the domain/URL of your link(s) being the same as, or containing, your user name, you appear to have linked to your own site. If you do so, you need to disclose that it's your site. If you don't disclose that it's your own site, it's often considered spam. See: [What signifies "Good" self promotion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212/165483) and [How to not be a spammer](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

Answer (score 1):

try this , it helped me out

```
sudo apt-get install -y libxml2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

A strategy I have found successful is to install R and R-Studio through anaconda (https://www.anaconda.com/). Create a separate environment for R and use the anaconda navigator to install R-Studio.

(Two great things about this approach: i) dependencies are automatically taken care of in the background ii) your working environment is sandboxed against accidents ... unless you're looking for trouble :-) )

I had the same issue with RStudio on Ubuntu 20.04 but switched to using R and R - Studio through anaconda.Tidyverse can be loaded without issues.

> library(tidyverse)
> ── Attaching packages ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse 1.3.1 ──
> ✓ ggplot2 3.3.5     ✓ purrr   0.3.4
> ✓ tibble  3.1.2     ✓ dplyr   1.0.7
> ✓ tidyr   1.1.3     ✓ stringr 1.4.0
> ✓ readr   1.4.0     ✓ forcats 0.5.1
> ── Conflicts ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse_conflicts() ──
> x dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
> x dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()